# compute nearest distance point to point inside a polygon pyqgis

Tags: shapefile, pyqgis, proximity

I need to compute the distance from an input point file to a series of target points in different shapefiles. Everything is in Africa. I want to do this in a pyQgis script. The script I have shown below does the job.

However, I would prefer if the aerial distances computed did not cross the sea. Is there a way to impose a restriction so that the distances are only computed to points inside a polygon (the African continent)?

```
import os
import glob
from qgis.core import * import qgis.utils 

  processing.runalg("qgis:distancematrix","path-to-my-input-file","inputfileid",atts,"path-to-my-target-file",0,1,"path-to-output-file")
```

Answer (score 1):

I think [Saga Least cost path](http://www.saga-gis.org/saga_tool_doc/2.2.0/grid_analysis_5.html) might do what you need.

You'll need to convert your Africa polygon to a raster and reclassify it so that land is a low value and sea is a high value. The tool will give you a line representative of the route taken which you can then calculate length on.